# C# Collection Data Structure With 1:1 Key/Value Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, hashtable

Are there any built-in C# data structures that are like a hash table but requires both the Keys and the Values to be unique among each other? I basically want a way to look up my Key object in a table via a unique Value and vice-versa. Next to maintaining two hash tables or iterating over each key in the hash table (which is slow), I cannot think of a better way to implement this.

Is the fact that I even have this request a sign that I am designing something incorrectly in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not necessarily a design flaw, but there's nothing built into the framework. Fortunately, there was a very similar question recently, and I [wrote an answer which should serve you well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/getting-key-of-value-of-a-generic-dictionary#255630).

Comment: Looks to be exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Google Collections calls this a [BiMap](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java#thiscanbeleftoutbutwasaddedtoovercomethecharacterlimit). Maybe you could port this to C#?