# What is the equivalent of TreeBidiMap in C#?

Tags: java, c#, dictionary

What is equivalent to `[TreeBidiMap][1]` in c# from [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) in Java?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c

Comment: It has an answer for you too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BidiMap` is an interface which defines map which allows mapping from key to value as well as from value to key (thus "bidirectional"). `TreeBidiMap` is the implementation of this interfaces which uses red-black tree.

None of this classes exist in .NET BCL per se, but I think those can be composed out of simpler primitives. Specifically, [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) provides an implementation of a red-black tree, and bidirectional map can be implemented on top of a standard `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.