# A data-structure for 1:1 mappings in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to temporary store some mapping data. The mapping is one to one. I saw this was solved in Python by wrapping two dictionaries in one class. In this case the O for  getting mapped value would be O(1). I wan't the same thing. Does .Net already have such structure or I have to implement my own with two dictionaries?

Comment: A very exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement it using two dictionaries. There's no built-in type in the base class library that efficiently supports indexing both by key and value.

Comment: I am not sure if author wants indexing by both key and value.

Comment: I can infer that from the need of *two dictionaries in Python*.

Comment: Well, if dataset is small, he can simply write a method to do lookup by value.

Comment: If the data set was small he should not have worried about Big-Oh.

Comment: Well, that's true. If he wants O(1) solution, he would need two dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, I want both key and value indexed and it should be fast too. I guess there is no built in structure if nobody has mentioned it then?

Comment: Trust me. There isn't. If you're still not convinced, just check out the list of collections yourself. They are all in the "System.Collections" namespace.