# Bidirecional dictionary WITH CASE-INSENSITIVENESS?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dictionary, bidirectional

Question: I use the bidirectional dicionary class I found here:
[Bidirectional 1 to 1 Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c)

The problem is, I need this - case insensitive (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

I wanna extend it to cover the IEqualityComparer constructor.
I've converted it to VB (works like a charm), but I have trouble implementing the comparer 'transfer'.

The problem is, in the parameters I have:

```
ByVal x As System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TKey)
```

But the dicionary secondToFirst is of type TValue, TKey, which kills my IEqualityComparer, which needs to be of type TValue instead of TKey...

How do I typecast this comparer ?

If somewhere there's another class for BiDictionaryOneToOne, with case-insensitiveness, that's also OK (as long as that library isn't monumental in size/memory consumption and .NET 2.0)

```
Public Class BiDictionaryOneToOne(Of TKey, TValue)


    Public Sub New(ByVal x As System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TKey))
        Dim y As System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TValue) = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase

        firstToSecond = New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)(x)
        secondToFirst = New Dictionary(Of TValue, TKey)(y)
    End Sub
```

**Edit:** 
OK, of course it's only possible if TKey & TValue are of type string, as John points out, but in case they are the same, it's still possible with try/catch like this:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal cmpFirstDirection As System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TKey))

    Try
        Dim cmpOppositeDirection As System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TValue) = CType(cmpFirstDirection, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TValue))
        firstToSecond = New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)(cmpFirstDirection)
        secondToFirst = New Dictionary(Of TValue, TKey)(cmpOppositeDirection)
    Catch ex As Exception
        firstToSecond = New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)(cmpFirstDirection)
        secondToFirst = New Dictionary(Of TValue, TKey)
    End Try

End Sub



Public Sub New(ByVal cmpFirstDirection As System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TKey), ByVal cmpOppositeDirection As System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TValue))
    firstToSecond = New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)(cmpFirstDirection)
    secondToFirst = New Dictionary(Of TValue, TKey)(cmpOppositeDirection)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write a *generic* bi-dictionary which could have *any* key/value pair combination of types. What does it mean to compare two integers using `StringComparer`? I suggest you change your constructor to take *two* `IEqualityComparer`s, one for `TKey` and one for `TValue`. You can then create a `BiDictionaryOneToOne(Of String, String)` which is case-insensitive by passing in two appropriate `IEqualityComparer(Of String)` values.