# Constraint where 2 generic types of a class must not be the same

Tags: c#, .net

How do I define a generic class where I have 2 types that *must* be different?

```
// General breeding - could be any animal/species with any animal/species
public abstract class Breed<TAnimal1, TAnimal2>
    where TAnimal1 : Animal
    where TAnimal2 : Animal
{
}

// Must breed among same animal/species
public abstract class IntraBreed<TAnimal> : Breed<TAnimal, TAnimal>
    where TAnimal : Animal
{
}

// Must breed between 2 different animals/species
public abstract class CrossBreed<TAnimal1, TAnimal2> : Breed<TAnimal1, TAnimal2>
    where TAnimal1 : Animal
    where TAnimal2 : Animal
    where TAnimal1 != TAnimal2 // I need something like this
{
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057285/7299782

Comment: There is no such generic constraint in the language. You'd have to enforce it at runtime.

Comment: @AnuViswan Thanks, that's something I didn't realize, and it's very helpful. Strange thing is, now I'm more worried about the `IntraBreed` more than `CrossBreed` :(