# Looking for a datastructure with a 1-to-1 unique dependency

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-structures, relational-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bidirectional 1 to 1 Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

Im curious if a datastructure exists in the standard .net libraries that can represent a 1-1 relationship, such as the following

```
1-a
4-b
6-c
5-d
```

Where I can say:

```
thisstructure[1] // returns "a"
thisstructure.GetKey["d"] // return 5
```

I understand all keys would have to be unique, does anything similar exist?

Thanks!

Comment: On the second line of code, did you mean return 5 or GetKey["a"]? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right dasblinkenlight.  My search-fu didn't come up with that dupe.

Comment: That's because you missed the "bidirectional" keyword :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this method fit your needs?

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TKey GetKey<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TValue value)
    {
        int index = dict.Values.ToList().IndexOf(value);

        if (index == -1)
        {
            return default(TKey); //or maybe throw an exception
        }

        return dict.Keys.ToList()[index];
    }
}
```

You could then use it like so:

```
Dictionary<int, char> dict = new Dictionary<int, char>();
dict.Add(1, 'a');
dict.Add(4, 'b');
dict.Add(6, 'c');
dict.Add(5, 'd');

Console.WriteLine(dict.GetKey('d')); //5
```

Comment: Yes, I think that would.

Answer (score 4):

Yes- it's called [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx).  It is intended to be subclassed and provides indexed access as well as access by a property derived from the added item.  I usually make a generic subclass:

```
public class GenericKeyedCollection<TKey, TValue> : KeyedCollection<TKey, TValue> {

    private readonly Func<TValue, TKey> _keyGenerator;

    public GenericKeyedCollection(Func<TValue, TKey> keyGenerator) {
        _keyGenerator = keyGenerator;
    }

    protected override int GetKeyForItem(TValue item)
   {
      return _keyGenerator(item);
   }
}
```

To use it:

```
var myCollection = new GenericKeyedCollection<String, Car>(c=>c.Model);
myCollection.Add(new Car("Ford", "Mustang"));
var byIndex = myCollection[0];
var byModel = myCollection["Mustang"];
```

The only caveat is that the derived property (the "key") mustn't change after the item has been added.

If your key is not a property of the value, then you can use a `Tuple<T1, T2>` to combine the key and value:

```
var myCollection = new GenericKeyedCollection<String, Tuple<String, Car>>(t=>t.Item1);
myCollection.Add(new Tuple<String, Car>("Foo", Car("Ford", "Mustang")));
var byIndexCar = myCollection[0].Item2;
var byItem1Car = myCollection["Foo"].Item2;
```

Comment: Is KeyedCollection unique to .NET 4 or was it around in earlier versions?

Comment: Can this be adopted to solve the OP's problem? It does not look like in the OP's case a key can be extracted from the value, which appears to be the requirement for `KeyedCollection<K,T>`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if the OP's value can be a `Tuple<WhateverHeHad, WhateverHeWantedAsAKey>` then yes.  I'll add that to the explanation.

Comment: @Nevyn been there since 2.0 according to the docs.

Comment: Learn something new every day.  Would have made my life easier if I had know about this 6 months ago when I needed to design something similar.  Oh well.  Maybe I'll get a chance to refactor my code at some point =D

Comment: Your edit makes sense, probably what OP is looking for. As such the concept of a "bidirectional keyed collection" doesn't make sense, because if you have the item, then you always have the key even without any collection. Keyed collection facilitates the other way need.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dictionary`....or `IDictionary` interface is the closest I can think of to what you want.  It doesn't have quite so simple a searching operation, in that searching on a value can return the key, but I do know you can search on a key to get a value.  providing functionality for the reverse in a custom extended class wouldn't be difficult at all.

[MSDN IDictionary page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx)

Comment: KeyedCollection is definitely the better way to go. It implements Dictionaries behind the scenes anyway =D