# C#: Is a SortedDictionary sorted when you enumerate over it?

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, enumeration

A SorteDictionary is according to MSDN sorted on the key. Does that mean that you can be sure that it will be sorted when you enumerate it in a foreach? Or does it just mean that the SortedDictionary works that way internally to have better performance in various cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you enumerate the collection it is sorted by keys (even if you enumerate say the `Values` collection). Internally the collection is implemented as a binary search tree (according to the documentation). Both insertion and lookup of values are O(log n) (meaning they are pretty efficient).

Answer (score 12):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8z05h2.aspx):

> The dictionary is maintained in a
>   sorted order using an internal tree.
>   Every new element is positioned at the
>   correct sort position, and the tree is
>   adjusted to maintain the sort order
>   whenever an element is removed. While
>   enumerating, the sort order is
>   maintained.

Comment: Lol. Where does it say that? I read like... all of it... must be getting blind...

Answer (score 1):

If you enumerate the items in a `SortedDictionary`, the items will be returned in the sort order of the item keys. And if you enumerate by the keys in the `SortedDictionary`, the keys will also be returned in sorted order. And perhaps somewhat surprisingly, if you enumerate the `SortedDictionary` by its values, the values are returned in the sort order of the keys, *not* the sort order of the values as you might expect.

**Demonstration:**

Note that in this demo the items added to the `SortedDictionary` are *not* added in sorted order.

Also, if you plan to enumerate your dictionary by its values and there is a possibility of **duplicate values**, consider having your reverse lookup function [return an IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22230811/1497596). (Of course, for large dictionaries, looking up a key by its value may result in poor performance.)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class SortedDictionaryEnumerationDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dict = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Add(4, "Four");
        dict.Add(5, "Five");
        dict.Add(1, "One");
        dict.Add(3, "Three");
        dict.Add(2, "Two");

        Console.WriteLine("== Enumerating Items ==");
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n== Enumerating Keys ==");
        foreach (int key in dict.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", key, dict[key]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n== Enumerating Values ==");
        foreach (string value in dict.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", value, GetKeyFromValue(dict, value));
        }
    }

    static int GetKeyFromValue(SortedDictionary<int, string> dict, string value)
    {
        // Use LINQ to do a reverse dictionary lookup.
        try
        {
            return
                (from item in dict
                 where item.Value.Equals(value)
                 select item.Key).First();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
== Enumerating Items ==
1 => One
2 => Two
3 => Three
4 => Four
5 => Five

== Enumerating Keys ==
1 => One
2 => Two
3 => Three
4 => Four
5 => Five

== Enumerating Values ==
One => 1
Two => 2
Three => 3
Four => 4
Five => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Edit: the part that says "Does that mean that you can be sure that it will be sorted when you enumerate it in a foreach?"

Comment: Is it guaranteed that it is sorted? (as compared to the the regular Dictionary where it is not)