# how to create a two way int-string dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, enums

I have a struct called: "BaseSprites"
I have some kind of list of BaseSprites called: "BaseSpritesList"
When my program loads in data, I want it to populate 'BaseSpritesList' by reading the contents of the folder it is loading from.
I want it to add 1 'BaseSprites' for each subfolder.
The name of the subfolder is essentially the name of the 'BaseSprites'

I then want to be able to quickly switch between the string (ie: the name), the int (ie: the index), and a the reference(ie: the specific 'BaseSprites' instance stored in BaseSpritesList).

If I wasn't doing this runtime, then I would create an enum "BaseType" and make BaseSpritesList a Dictionary.

Comment: You might wanna try a similar implementation for two way int-string here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966331/two-way-bidirectional-dictionary-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem. I created my own class. It contains a list of strings (names) and a list of objects of any type. It has 6 get methods that can interchange between the string, int and object any way.