# From Dictionary to List

Tags: c#, dictionary

This is a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> Dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I want to do the following: when I click a button the first dictionary (Dic) key and its values are copied to a list (`List<string>`). Click again, and the same thing happens, but this time with the next dictionary key and value.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.  Do you mean you want to add a list to a Dictionary? Or are you having problems with accessing the List<string>?

Comment: There is no definite order in Dictionary.

Comment: What about your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12312240/961113)

Comment: Hydev, no ) I want copy elements from Dictionary to List

Comment: helping you would be much simpler if you add an example with the content of the dictionary and the contento of the list after each click...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to create a new `List<string>` based on your all string elements in the dictionary's List values. You may use `SelectMany` to flatten it out and get a list using the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> Dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
Dic.Add("1", new List<string>{"ABC","DEF","GHI"});
Dic.Add("2", new List<string>{"JKL","MNO","PQR"});
Dic.Add("3", new List<string>{"STU","VWX","YZ"});

List<string> strList = Dic.SelectMany(r => r.Value).ToList();
```

Where `strList` will contain all the string items from the dictionary in a single list.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `ToList` method?

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary["cat"] = 1;
dictionary["dog"] = 4;
dictionary["mouse"] = 2;
dictionary["rabbit"] = -1;

// Call ToList.
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> list = dictionary.ToList();

// Loop over list.
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}", pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: i have Dictionary<string, List<string>> Dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();------------------ no Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();