# How do you get rid of the $type property returned from an MVC web api method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm calling a web API I wrote using an MVC4 ApiController.

It returns a `Dictionary<int, int>` like this:

```
return Request.CreateResponse<Dictionary<int, int>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, histogram);
```

This returns the following JSON object:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
  "4": 113,
  "0": 716,
  "1": 443,
  "2": 226,
  "3": 123,
  "5": 4,
  "26": 3
}
```

This object has a `$type` property that refers to the .NET type it corresponds to.  I don't want this to be sent to my client.

How can I get rid of the `$type` property?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636885/remove-item-in-dictionary-based-on-value

Comment: Don't return a dictionary, it's specific only to .NET and meaningless to any consumer of your api that is not a .NET client.

Comment: My API call is just supposed to return some key/value pairs as a JSON object.  I know a dictionary is specific to .NET; that just happens to be how the key/value pairs are represented in my controller.  The `$type` property is not in the dictionary I'm returning.  MVC seems to be adding the property on its own.

Comment: Try returning the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was going on.  Basically, I did it to myself.

I needed to make a change to my `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // ...

    // remove this line:
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects;
}
```

After I removed that line, the `$type` property stopped showing up in the results of my API controller methods.

Which begs the question: is it possible to use the `$type` property to instantiate the correct class during incoming calls to the web API, while leaving the `$type` property out of the outgoing JSON or XML?

Answer (score 0):

do not return dictionary as it was already mentioned before you better converting the the 
 histogram to jsson in your back-end

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( histogram, Formatting.Indented, new   JsonSerializerSettings
       {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
      });

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
```