# How to delete an item from List of Dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#

Here is the values I am adding in Dictionary List:-

```
1,1000
2,2000
1,1000
3,3000
```

I can delete from Dictionary based on key value:-

```
if (i == null)
    return;
var dict = app["ItemList"] as Dictionary<int, int>;
if (dict != null)
    dict.Remove(i.ItemId);
```

Here I pass key value (i.ItemId),it deletes an item from dictionary. But When I use List of Dictionary, I couldn't delete items from List of Dictionary based on Key Value.

```
if (i == null)
    return;
var dict = app["ItemList"] as List<Dictionary<int, int>>;
if (dict != null)
{
    var itemDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    itemDict[i.ItemUid] = 0;
    dict.Remove(itemDict);
}
```

Note:- I have only Key value available when I am deleting from List of Dictionary.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: can u refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636885/remove-item-in-dictionary-based-on-value

Comment: No.. delete a record from List-Dictionary-int,int--. I understood how to delete from Dictionary-int,int-

Comment: You need to identify and retrieve the dictionary from the list first. How do you intend to distinguish the dictionaries inside the list?

Comment: @MongZhu. When I have to delete, I have only Key value available. I need to delete all records where Key value is matching.

Comment: Does the `ItemUid` exist only in one of the dictionaries inside your list? Or can it occur in multiple dictionaries? If it is unique then you can check for it

Comment: itemUid exists in multiple dictionaries... That is the reason I have used List of Dictionary instead of just Dictionary.. Coz keys can be duplicate.

Comment: Just go over all dictionaries in a list with foreach and delete item from each one.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you loop through the list and delete all records in each dictionary like you did in the first example

Comment: Or do you aim explicitly for a linq  solution?

Comment: Dictionary does not implement equality like that.  Two identical Dictionary are not Equal.   Question is not clear.  VTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that i.ItemUid is a key:

```
var dict = app["ItemList"] as List<Dictionary<int, int>>;
if (dict != null)
{
    foreach (var x in dict) x.Remove(i.ItemUid);
}
```

If instead i.ItemUid is a key-value pair

```
var dict = app["ItemList"] as List<Dictionary<int, int>>;
if (dict != null)
{
    foreach (var x in dict) x.Remove(i.ItemUid.Key);
}
```

**Edit:** total number of keys in all dictionaries:

```
int totalNumberOfKeys = 0;
foreach (var x in dict) totalNumberOfKeys += x.Count;
```

Comment: ItemUid is a key... And first example is kind of working. It deleted matched records but dict.Count is still same.  How do i get rid of empty items, if you can help. THanks

Comment: @user1327064 why do you expect the count of `dict` to change? For that you would have to remove an entire dictionary from the list

Comment: @user1327064: probably you are thinking that dict.Count is the total number of keys... it is not! If you want that number, see the following edit to my answer.