# Get dictionary value by key

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

How can I get the dictionary value by a key on a function?

My function code (and the command I try doesn't work):

```
static void XML_Array(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array)
{
    String xmlfile = Data_Array.TryGetValue("XML_File", out value);
}
```

My button code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Data_Array.Add("XML_File", "Settings.xml");

    XML_Array(Data_Array);
}
```

I want on the `XML_Array` function the variable to be:

```
string xmlfile = "Settings.xml":
```

Comment: Re *"the command I try doesn't work"*: What happens? What are the symptoms?

Comment: see also [Is there an IDictionary implementation that, on missing key, returns the default value instead of throwing?](//stackoverflow.com/q/538729)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
String xmlfile = Data_Array["XML_File"];
```

Note that if the dictionary doesn't have a key that equals `"XML_File"`, that code will throw an exception. If you want to check first, you can use TryGetValue like this:

```
string xmlfile;
if (!Data_Array.TryGetValue("XML_File", out xmlfile)) {
   // the key isn't in the dictionary.
   return; // or whatever you want to do
}
// xmlfile is now equal to the value
```

Answer (score 153):

Just use the key name on the dictionary. C# has this:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 dict.Add("UserID", "test");
 string userIDFromDictionaryByKey = dict["UserID"];
```

If you look at the tip suggestion:

[image]

Comment: It throws an exception if the key does not exist. That is why other people's answers suggest that you should use TryGetValue.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason that others are suggesting TryGetValue. My solution is simplification, which I was not aware of. When I've found it out, I've pasted it here. And it seems that a lot of others didn't know about that also. Otherwise, they could also paste this answer and add that throws exception if key doesn't exist. Anyway, thanks for warning.

Comment: For some reason I always forget this with Dictionaries... Like it doesn't seem like it should be this straightforward.

Comment: Still a good solution when you know that values will always exiist. If not, it would still recommend the answers that suggest using TryGetValue().

Comment: If your code is throwing an exception because the key does not exist - where you are trying to "get the value from a dictionary by key", there is possibly an underlying issue with your code.  Your key range should be limited to keys that exist in the dictionary.

Answer (score 42):

That is not how the `TryGetValue` works. It returns `true` or `false` based on whether the key is found or not, and sets its `out` parameter to the corresponding value if the key is there.

If you want to check if the key is there or not and do something when it's missing, you need something like this:

```
bool hasValue = Data_Array.TryGetValue("XML_File", out value);
if (hasValue) {
    xmlfile = value;
} else {
    // do something when the value is not there
}
```

Comment: I have no use for hasValue :
if (Data_Array.TryGetValue("XML_File", out value)) {
    xmlfile = value;
} else {
    // do something when the value is not there
}

Comment: CS0103: The name 'value' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @ViktorMS I didn't pollute the answer with a declaration. In c#6 you can add `var` to combine it with a declaration.

Answer (score 33):

```
Dictionary<String, String> d = new Dictionary<String, String>();
d.Add("1", "Mahadev");
d.Add("2", "Mahesh");
Console.WriteLine(d["1"]); // It will print Value of key '1'
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46582244/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 12):

```
static void XML_Array(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array)
{
    String value;
    if(Data_Array.TryGetValue("XML_File", out value))
    {
        // ... Do something here with value ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
static String findFirstKeyByValue(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array, String value)
{
    if (Data_Array.ContainsValue(value))
    {
        foreach (String key in Data_Array.Keys)
        {
            if (Data_Array[key].Equals(value))
                return key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? *"How can I get the dictionary value by a key"* An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21003143/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Is this the answer to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444033/get-dictionary-key-by-value)?

Answer (score 4):

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>{
  {1,"item1"},
  {2,"item2"},
  {3,"item3"},
}

int key = 2 // for example
string result = dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key] : null;
```

Comment: This would search for the key twice in the dictionary. Why not use the out parameter of  TryGetValue instead of searching a second time? Even with your code: Why even use TryGetValue instead of ContainsKey if you want to go that route?

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Data_Array.Add("XML_File", "Settings.xml");

    XML_Array(Data_Array);
}

static void XML_Array(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array)
{
    String xmlfile = Data_Array["XML_File"];
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What was changed? What was the fix? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21310319/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example which I use in my source code.
I am getting **key** and **value** from Dictionary from element 0 to number of elements in my Dictionary. Then I fill my string[] array which I send as a parameter after in my function which accept only params string[]

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> listKomPop = addElements();
int xpopCount = listKomPop.Count;
if (xpopCount > 0)
{
    string[] xpostoci = new string[xpopCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < xpopCount; i++)
    {
        /* here you have key and value element */
        string key = listKomPop.Keys.ElementAt(i);
        decimal value = listKomPop[key];

        xpostoci[i] = value.ToString();
    }
...
```

This solution works with SortedDictionary also.

Answer (score 2):

I use a similar method to dasblinkenlight's in a function to return a single key value from a Cookie containing a JSON array loaded into a Dictionary as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a single key Value from a Json filled cookie with 'cookiename','key' 
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetSpecialCookieKeyVal(string _CookieName, string _key)
    {
        //CALL COOKIE VALUES INTO DICTIONARY
        Dictionary<string, string> dictCookie =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>
         (MyCookinator.Get(_CookieName));

        string value;
        if (dictCookie.TryGetValue( _key, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }

    }
```

Where "MyCookinator.Get()" is another simple Cookie function getting an http cookie overall value.

Comment: There isn't anyone here by the name "dasblinkenlight". What answer does it refer to?

Answer (score 0):

(I posted this on another question and I don't know how to link to that so here it is)
A Dictionary<K,V> extension that works. I have been using it for a long time::

```
public static bool TryGetKey<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> instance, V value, out 
K key)
{
    foreach (var entry in instance)
    {
        if (!entry.Value.Equals(value))
        {
            continue;
        }
        key = entry.Key;
        return true;
    }
    key = default(K);
    return false;
}
```

And use as :

```
public static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"1", "one"},
        {"2", "two"},
        {"3", "three"}
    };
 
     string value="two"; 
     if (dict.TryGetKey(value, out var returnedKey))
         Console.WriteLine($"Found Key {returnedKey}");
     else
         Console.WriteLine($"No key found for value {value}");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (Data_Array["XML_File"] != "") String xmlfile = Data_Array["XML_File"];
```

Comment: You have got some [explaining](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54096267/edit) to do. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).