# How to pull the key value based on the key that is inside the Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dictionary

Let's say I did the following:

```
Dictionary<string,NetworkStream> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,NetworkStream>();
dictionary.add("Matt",network);
dictionary.add("Mike",network);
dictionary.add("Jack",network);
```

How do I pull the `Networkstream` of Jack? Assuming I have multiple of lines likes this.

UPDATE: I didn't explain myself well, sorry. If the name is already exists I'm not going to add him to the dictionary.. I meant if I have different names.

Comment: it is not possible that you have multiple lines containing the key "Jack" - you'd get `key already exists exception`. To retrieve by key: `dictionary["Jack"]`

Comment: Multiple lines of what? You can't have more than one "Jack" as a key. Dictionary keys are unique

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @viveknuna I updated the question

Comment: @SteelSoul Updated the question.

Comment: @NateS that's still unclear ; if you have different name of what ?

Comment: @NateS after you updated the question, Sajeetharan's answer is correct. You should try and learn how to use a class before trying to  use it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get dictionary value by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169443/get-dictionary-value-by-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary cannot have more than one key with same name, still you can access the value of 'Jack' like this,

```
value = dictionary["Jack"];
```

Comment: @NateS if you are updating keys with different names, above solution should work

Comment: @NateS you are welcome, mark as answer if it had helped

Comment: I'm trying but it's telling me: " Thanks for the feedback. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded., But do not change the publicly displayed post score. "