# C# accessing data from dictionary

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, models

So I have a dictionary which is used to store deserialized JSON data into models in ASP.NET MVC.

```
Dictionary<string, prosjekt.Models.GamesInfoModel.Datas>
```

Example of how the models look like:

```
public class Data
{
public string name {get; set;}
 //etc
}

public class Datas
{
public bool success { get; set; }
public Data data { get; set; }    
}
```

My problem is accessing the data from the

```
prosjekt.Models.GamesInfo.Data
```

which lies under the prosjekt.Models.GamesInfo.Datas in the dictionary.

So how do I access the data from the model/object Data? For example getting it into a variable/list or writing the values to the console.

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve an object from a dictionary?

Comment: `dictionary[key].data` this is how you access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get dictionary value by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169443/get-dictionary-value-by-key)

Comment: Minor nitpick: **data** is already plural, and it's a bad name for a model anyway. I'll guess these are just example names.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks that worked. Is there an easy way to get the data into a list?

Comment: var dataList  = dictionary.Select(item => item.Value.data).ToList();

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you, you have been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
GamesInfo.Data variable = yourDictionary["YourKey"];
```

Although you probably want to make sure the key exists first, so it won't throw an execption.

See this other SO question : [get dictionary value by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169443/get-dictionary-value-by-key)