# Convert text to number in DomainUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DomainUpDown` window. I need to read the value from `DomainUpDown` window and next check this in my `if()`. For example I give the code:
How to do it properly?

```cs
string a;
if(DomainUpDown.Text == "Text1")
{
    a="0";
}
else
{
    a="1";
}
```

Comment: Is this winforms?

Comment: Yes.......................

Comment: What is wring with what you have...other than neither `"0"` nor `"1"` are *numbers*?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

Comment: Without seeing any context we cant tell if there is a better way - but there is nothing wrong with your code if the requirement is `set the variable string a to the value "1" or "0" depending on the text property of the object DomainUpDown`

Comment: If you have more cases, you could use a dictionary with keys like DomainUpDown values and you'll read it like `string a = yourDictionary[DomainUpDown.Text]`. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169443/get-dictionary-value-by-key)

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it to this (I suppose your number should be an integer):

```
int myNumber = DomainUpDown.Text == "Text1" ? 0 : 1;
```