# Change the dictionary on c# model

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary and I need to change the dictionary on c# model.How to do it?

```
var number = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"One", 1},
        {"Two", 2},  
        {"Three", 3}

   };
```

Model:

```
public class Number
{
    public double One{ get; set; }
    public double Two { get; set; }
    public double Three { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `public double One{ get {return number["One"];} set {return number["One"] = (int) value;}}`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12169443/993547.

Comment: You could generate an constructor in the Number Class: 
`public Number(Dictionary<string, int> numbers)
        {
            One = numbers["One"];
            Two = numbers["Two"];
            Three = numbers["Three"];
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Reflection to get the properties on the Model and update the same on the dictionary like below where obj is the model object

```
var propertyCollection = typeof(Number).GetProperties();
foreach (var item in propertyCollection)
{
    if (number.ContainsKey(item.Name.ToString()))
    {
        number[item.Name.ToString()] = Int32.Parse(item.GetValue(obj));
    }
}
```

Comment: if the values in the dictionary are statically (they dont change), its better to use the key as an index because reflection is slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to change the dictionary to class, then you should change your class structure to below (key-value pair)

```
    public class Number
    {
        public string number { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
        public Number(string number, double value)
        {
            this.number = number;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

and inject the values to class by creating an object of list of number

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Number> numbers = new List<Number>();
        numbers.Add(new Number("One", 1));
        numbers.Add(new Number("Two", 2));
        numbers.Add(new Number("Three", 3));
    }
```