# A two way KeyValuePair collection in C#

Tags: c#, linq, collections, dictionary, key-value

By creating a `Dictionary<int,int>` or `List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>` I can create a list of related ids.

By calling `collection[key]` I can return the corresponding value stored against it.

**I also want to be able to return the key by passing in a value** - [which I know is possible using some LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444033/get-dictionary-key-by-value), however it doesn't seem very efficient.

**In my case along with each key being unique, each value is too**. Does this fact make it possible to use another approach which will provide better performance?

Comment: If keys and values are of the same type and distinct, you could add both associations (`k -> v`, `v -> k`) to the same dictionary, as long as you don't need to know which is which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need a bi-directional dictionary. There are no framework classes that support this, but you can implement your own:

[Bidirectional 1 to 1 Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate two dictionaries, one with your "keys" storing your values and the other keyed with your "values" storing your keys.

Then manage access to them through a few methods. Fast and the added memory overhead shouldn't make a huge difference.

Edit: just noticed this is essentially the same as the previous answer :-/