# Get Key From String Where Value Is List<string>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary where the key is string and the value is a list of strings.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
    {"alpha", new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"}}
    {"beta", new List<string> {"four", "five", "six"}}
    {"gamma", new List<string> {"seven", "eight", "nine"}}
}
```

Is there a way to return the key when given a string that exist in the value?

For example, given `"four"`, return `"beta"`

I found something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444033/get-dictionary-key-by-value), but it works only when the value is single and not a list, and I don't know how I can do this with a list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching a dictionary by value is not efficient, however:

```
string firstKey = dict.Where(kv => kv.Value.Contains("four"))
    .Select(kv => kv.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault(); // returns null if no list contains "four"
```

or you could provide a default key if no list contains a given value, then it's safe to use `First`:

```
string firstKey = dict.Where(kv => kv.Value.Contains("foo"))
    .Select(kv => kv.Key)
    .DefaultIfEmpty("--no value found--")
    .First(); // result: "--no value found--"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is there could be multiple keys for any given string value.  Hence you would need to return a collection versus a single key.  This could be done as follows

```
IEnumerable<string> FindAllKeys(Dictionary<string, List<string>> map, string value) {
  foreach (var pair in map) {
    if (pair.Value.IndexOf(value) >= 0) {
      yield return pair.Key;
    }
  }
}
```

If you wanted to cut this search off at the first match you could just employ the `FirstOrDefault` extension method

```
FindAllKeys(dict, "four").FirstOrDefault();
```