# Accessing key from value

Tags: c#

I want to access key from value. and I am able to access value from key.
My json file look as

```
{
    "screen": {
        "0": "42x11",
        "1": "16x16",
        "2": "40x30",
        "3": "32x32",
        "4": "42x32",
        "5": "48x32",
        "6": "60x40",
        "7": "150x40",
        "8": "84x48"
    },
    "os": {
        "0": {
            "versions": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "10"
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "8"
                },
                "3": {
                    "name": "7"
                }
            },
            "name": "Windows"
        }
    },
    "app": {
        "1": {
            "name": "javaScript1",
            "versions": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "1.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have parsed the file with the help of JavaScriptSerializer as.

```
public void deserialize_metadata()
{
   using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\vikash.kumar\\Desktop\\metadatainfo.json"))
   {
        var json = r.ReadToEnd();
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("dict" + dict["screen"]["0"]);    //o/p - 42x11
        Console.WriteLine("dict" + dict["app"]["1"]["name"]); //o/p - javaScript1
      }
}
```

It works fine when we want to access value from key.

How we can access key from value by this process?

Comment: In that case you should add the information into the question.

Comment: Okk Ankush I have mentioned in edit

Comment: @VikashKumar And why not?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have tried to use as dict["screen"].value  then .value was throwing error

Comment: What error....?

Comment: I have used as **if(dict["screen"].value.equals("42x11"))**  and exception occured as **Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'value'' **

Comment: `Value` and `value` are different, C# is **case sensitive**. Also `dict["screen"]` should already return the "value"

Comment: @Rafalon then also same error occurred with Value

Comment: @Rafalon if i use just dict["screen"] in Console.WriteLine then ** System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] ** get printed

Comment: There's no such thing as `var` type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How do you mean?  If you mean where he's calling `var json = r.ReadToEnd();` in C#?  This is strongly-typed because `ReadToEnd()` returns a string, so the type of `json` at compile time is `string`.  Are you suggesting this might be contributing to the problem?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var

Comment: @Trevor - 4 hours ago, the OP removed their edit stating "There is no option to use .value and .key property in variable of var type.". It was to this I was objecting. It seemed to indicate they were at the point of confusion, often reached with people first learning about `var` in C# that it's somehow a different type rather than being a compiler trick that still leads to an actual type being selected for the variable.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Fair enough, I didn't see it before the edit.  I completely agree that it suggests confusion over how `var` works.

Comment: Thanks guys my problem got sorted by Rafalon's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444033/get-dictionary-key-by-value), try: `dict["screen"].FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "42x11")?.Key`

I added `?.` to take care of the possibility that `.FirstOrDefault` can return `null` if there's no match. This way it won't throw an exception but only return `null`.

**Edit**

```
Console.WriteLine((dict["screen"] as Dictionary<string, dynamic>)
                      .First(x => x.Value == "16x16").Key);
```

Comment: **Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type** error is showing at x=>x.value == "42x11"

Comment: Oh right, that's because of the `dynamic` you used in your json deserializer. Maybe you could create a class that matches your json's format and explicitly tell that `dict["screen"]` is a `Dictionary<string,string>` or just try to cast it this way (`var scr = dict["screen"] as Dictionary<string,string>;` then `scr.FirstOrDefault(...)`)

Comment: Okay but  how we can express app then,,

Comment: You could do it like that:  `Console.WriteLine((dict["screen"] as Dictionary<string, dynamic>).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "16x16").Key);`

Comment: @VikashKumar this is a different question, but if your json isn't really dynamic, then maybe you should consider having a class with `screen`, `os`, and `app` **fields** having respectively `Dictionary<string,string>`, `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` and `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` **types**. You would then access `dict.screen` instead of `dict["screen"]`. Or you could go further and completely remove `dynamic`

Comment: Thanks  my problem is solved