# Most efficient way to remove a value from a series of lists within a dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a Dictionary set up like so:

```C#
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> Directory = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I am needing to iterate over every Key in the Dictionary and remove all occurrences of a string within each of the lists.

I believe I can do so with a series of for/for-each loops, possibly by creating a new list for each without the string that I am trying to remove but I feel this may become inefficient when the Dictionary grows in size.

Are there any methods that can make this more efficient?

Comment: `foreach (var list in Directory.Values) list.RemoveAll(item => item == "SomeValue");`

Comment: What about using `Directory.Values.ForEach(list => list.RemoveAll(...)));`?

Comment: Use this method for every key. `List<T>.Remove(T)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get dictionary key by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444033/get-dictionary-key-by-value)

Comment: @cillsley If you are not storing duplicate string values in the Lists, you could use `HashSet<string>` instead of `List<T>` as your values in the dictionary and use the `.Remove(T)` method of `HashSet`

Comment: @fredrik This looks like it would be the simplest solution, thanks!

Comment: @cillsley You can use a linq expression to remove the item from all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        dictionary.Add("Test1", new List<string>() { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" });
        dictionary.Add("Test2", new List<string>() { "Test2", "Test3", "Test1" });
        dictionary.Add("Test3", new List<string>() { "Test3", "Test2", "Test1" });
        dictionary.RemoveStringFromEveryList("Test1");
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void RemoveStringFromEveryList(this Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary, string wordToRemove)
    {
        foreach(var keyValue in dictionary)
        {
            keyValue.Value.RemoveAll(x => x == wordToRemove);
        }
    }
}
```

I would use an extension method for a better usage and readability of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a traditional `foreach` loop

```
var strToRemove == "remove me!";
foreach (var listObj in dic.Values)
{
    listObj.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals(strToRemove ,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RemoveAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.8) in a foreach loop to remove all occurence in all lists of a specified string :

```
foreach (var val in Directory.Values)
{
    var numberOfElementsRemoved = val.RemoveAll(x => x.ToLower() == StringToRemove.ToLower());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Where statement to look up the pair that has the value you need to remove... then update the value of that pair.

```
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> Directory = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    Directory.Add("1", new List<string>() { "alpha", "bravo", "charlie" });
    Directory.Add("2", new List<string>() { "delta", "echo", "foxtrot" });
    Directory.Add("3", new List<string>() { "golf", "charlie", "India" });

    string stringToRemove = "charlie";
    Directory.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(stringToRemove))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => x.Value.Remove(stringToRemove));
```

After the execution, "charlie" is gone from all dictionary's pairs.

As per Cid's suggestion, you can also use `RemoveAll(lambda)` if you dont have a distinct list.

```
Directory.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(stringToRemove))
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(x => x.Value.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals(strToRemove ,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: This looks nice and clean! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: `Remove` removes only the first occurence in the list.

Comment: The lists will only contain one occurrence anyways so this should work fine!

Comment: Added the note with addition of how you can use RemoveAll to remove all instances of the string from the Dictionary's list.