# Search for Value as if it were key in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am planning to write a C# application that reads from a video game's memory and lists the various active objects in the current level. I have completely mapped out each object's unique identifier, resulting in a large list of String:UInt32 pairs. Since I'm aiming to have this program update object statuses in near real-time, I need a way of being able to cross reference Strings with their respective UInt32s and vice versa.

Normally, I would use a Dictionary map for this task. However, I know that Dictionaries are often purposed to allow dynamic values paired with a key, meaning that you can get the value from a key efficiently, but cannot get the key with a value without iterating through each key until the correct one is found. The data I will be storing will be constant.

Is there a way for me to create a Key:Key structure to allow efficient cross referencing the Strings and UInt16s with their respective counterparts? At the very least, is there a way to search through a dictionary as if the value were a key itself?

Comment: what if the key was a hash of the object?

Comment: "_The data I will be storing will be constant._" then why not make that constant value the key instead?  I'm not clear on what you mean here.

Comment: Both the key and the value will be constant. I need a data structure that allows me to look up one or the other, but Dictionaries do not support search via Value

Comment: use two dictionaries. the second dictionary holds values as key and keys as value from 1st dictionary

Comment: there are many answers that solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444033/get-dictionary-key-by-value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001908/get-dictionary-key-by-using-the-dictionary-value