# LINQ: Getting Keys for a given list of Values from Dictionary and vice versa

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have the following structure in my code `Dictionary<TKeys, TValues> data;`.
I run some LINQ queries on both data types and often need to switch between `Keys` and `Values`.
What is the best way to get the list of Keys for given Values and vice versa?
Please, notice, that I usually have 'IEnumerable' and 'IEnumerable' as a result of my previous LINQ queries and would like to have something like `IEnumerable<TKeys> Dictionary.GetAllKeys(IEnumerable<IValues> vals)` and `IEnumerable<TValues> Dictionary.GetAllValues(IEnumerable<IKeys> keys)`.

Maybe I need other data container for this task?

Regards,
Alexander.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
 var values = dictionary.Where(x => someKeys.Contains(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value);
 var keys = dictionary.Where(x => someValues.Contains(x.Value)).Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your answer implies that I have a single "someKey" or "someValue". In my case I have them as `IEnumerable<T1>` or `IEnumerable<T2>`.

Comment: @Alaudo I didn't realize that. In that case you will have to use `Contains()`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I editted my question to make it clearer. 
Your solution almost did it, I would prefer not to get the list of values, but rather a new dictionary as the outcome of the LINQ query. So, following your answer, I get 
`var newdict = dictionary.Where(x => someKeys.Contains(x.Key)).ToDictionary();`
This last `ToDictionary()` does not work for me.

Comment: @Alaudo Try `var newdict = dictionary.Where(x => someKeys.Contains(x.Key)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.Value);`

Answer (score 11):

A `Dictionary<,>` really isn't great for finding keys by value. You could write a bidirectional dictionary, as [I have done in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/getting-key-of-value-of-a-generic-dictionary#255630), but it wouldn't *necessarily* be the best approach.

Of course you *can* use a dictionary as a sequence of key/value pairs, so you could have:

```
var keysForValues = dictionary.Where(pair => values.Contains(pair.Value))
                              .Select(pair => pair.Key);
```

Just be aware this will be an O(n) operation, even if your "values" is a `HashSet` or something similar (with an efficient containment check).

EDIT: If you don't *really* need a key/value relation - if it's more like they're just pairs - then using `List<Tuple<Foo, Bar>>` would make a certain amount of sense. The query ends up being the same, basically:

```
public IEnumerable<T1> GetAllFirst<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> source,
                                           IEnumerable<T2> seconds)
{
    HashSet<T2> secondsSet = new HashSet<T2>(seconds);
    return source.Where(pair => secondsSet.Contains(pair.Item2));
}

public IEnumerable<T2> GetAllSecond<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> source,
                                            IEnumerable<T1> firsts)
{
    HashSet<T1> firstsSet = new HashSet<T1>(firsts);
    return source.Where(pair => firstsSet.Contains(pair.Item1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and quick answer!
What I basically need is to 1:1 mapping between two generic lists, so that I can easily run queries against one list and get the directly mapped values from the second list for my next query. I was thinking about a list of tuples for this case. Is there any established practice in LINQ here? Regards,Alexander.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will consider this solution during my next major refactoring. I got an interesting solution for my question from @Bala R, which allows me to stick to Dictionary, for I have already implemented a bunch of queries against this structure.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to perform your linq query on the collection of key-value pairs, then use a Select projection to select either the Keys or the Values at the end of your query. This way there is no need to perform a look-up at the end of your query.

For example:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  // select all values for keys that contain the letter 'A'
  var values = data.Where(pair => pair.Key.Contains("A"))
                   .Select(pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: I editted my question to make it clearer that I have a list of values and keys, not just single values. Can I feed `IEnumerable<>` as an input for the `Contains()` predicate?

Comment: I would definitely convert the selected value to a string and use firstordefault for safety. That way you have something in the value and it won't blow up.

data.Where(pair => pair.Key.Contains("A"))
.Select(pair => pair.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault(),