# Get key by value in hash table c#

Tags: c#, hashtable

I want to get the key of my value but this does not Possible in Hashtable 
Is there data stretcher to do this ??

```
    Hashtable x = new Hashtable();
    x.Add("1", "10");
    x.Add("2", "20");
    x.Add("3", "30");

    x.GetKey(20);//equal 2
```

Comment: You can do that with a dictionary.

See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/getting-key-of-value-of-a-generic-dictionary

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose of the `Hashtable`. Why would you do that? BTW: Since .NET 2.0 you should be using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all your keys are strings.

```
var key = x.Keys.OfType<String>().FirstOrDefault(s => x[s] == "20")
```

or better use a Dictionary instead:

```
Dictionary<string, string> x = new Dictionary<string, string>();
x.Add("1", "10");
x.Add("2", "20");
x.Add("3", "30");

string result = x.Keys.FirstOrDefault(s => x[s] == "20");
```

If you know that your value will always have just one distinct key, use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) instead of [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault).

Comment: Thank you Dictionary is better

Answer (score 3):

If you looking for O(1) solution, then you may need to implement the reversed `Hashtable` as well where the value of this table will be key and key becomes corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq operators

```
x.Keys.OfType<String>().FirstOrDefault(a => x[a] == "20")
```

You can iterate with foreach

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use two `Dictionary<string, string>` but this would mean that their is a 1-1 relationship between the items:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dict1.Add("1", "10");
dict2.Add("10", "1");

dict1.Add("2", "20");
dict2.Add("20", "2");

dict1.Add("3", "30");
dict2.Add("30", "3");

var valueOfDictOne = dict1["1"];
var valueOfDictTwo = dict2["10"];
```