# Ensure that a user (or a database was read) is used only by one application

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

Imagine that I have 100 users list in the database and I have 100 or more console applications that are using those users to log in somewhere. I need to use a unique user per application, I must not use the same user more than one application. How can I solve this issue, what is the best practice or pattern for that? That means a record has to read only one application/service I have also some requirements/restrictions as I mentioned below.

1. Each application/service an instance of a microservice. So, it can be scale-down or scale-up. It means I cannot set a user to a specific application/service in a config file.
2. Users in the database can be disabled or removed in the future or added new users. So user count is not fixed.

Comment: Why have the list? You could separate it out into a file per app, then the apps can't "accidentally" use the same user

Comment: Have you considered using multiple threads (one thread per user) instead of multiple applications? Synchronizing applications is more difficult that synchronizing threads.

Comment: @CoderLee thanks for your reply, I updated my question, I think you can find your question's answer there now.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks for your reply, I am using a kind of microservice architecture and I have updated my question. Please let me know if it is not clear still.

Comment: What is the question 1) Allow only one user access the database.  Make sure if a 2nd application by same user is locked out.  Which is  what the title says. 2) Have a separate log file for each user/application.   Which is what the text says in your request.

Comment: @leo What is your goal here? I don't understand why you want to do this. Some more clarity will help to give you better answers

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what database you use or what database access technology stack. In general, you need the following:

- a field in the database that signals whether a row is in use
- each application:

  - locks the table
  - grabs a row that is not in use
  - updates the in-use flag to "currently used"
  - releases the lock on the table
  - uses this user in the program
  - makes sure that it releases the in-use flag when it's done

Any decent database and any decent driver should be able to do that.

Answer (score -1):

If I don't misunderstand you, you need a class that handles 1:1 relationships between two classes. Maybe you can find an answer [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832227/net-dictionary-with-forced-unique-values)