# Two-way key value collection

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

Is there a collection in C# working like dictionary with multiple keys allowing bidirectional access? For example:

```
Collection<int, string> a = new Collection<int, string>();
a.Add(1, "a");
a.Add(1, "b");
a.Add(2, "a");
a.Get(1);//returns ["a", "b"]
a.InverseGet("a"); //returns [1, 2]
```

Comment: You have LINQ for that.

Comment: A simple `.Where()` would do the job if you don't care about performance that much

Comment: Another option is the DataTable. It doesn't care about directions and can use indexes to improve performance

Comment: You should use a list of key value pairs. `var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();` This you can query with LINQ easily.

Comment: @Linuxrocks there's no need to use a KVP, an array of tuples will work just as well

Comment: @quarando what do you want to do? Why not just use an array of tuples? Are there any performance requirements?

Comment: try to use [`Lookup<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) and it's `Where` method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: He wrote about keys and then I naturally think of KVP. Tuples are for equaly values. But I think you're right. Tuples are in his case probably better since they implement `IComparable`and `IStructuralEquatable` making it easy to compare two tuples.

Comment: @SanjayNishad: He has not have unique keys.

Comment: @linuxrocks ic, I found [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b942f9/a-dictionary-class-which-permits-duplicate-keys/) may help him

Comment: For those reviewing my proposed edit, I later found the question it **should** be a duplicate of (with answer from @JonSkeet similar to Adam G's answer below), but don't know how to propose an edit to the duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/getting-multiple-keys-of-specified-value-of-a-generic-dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that gives you the performance of a dictionary lookup in both directions. I assume that you want to ignore duplicate tuples and the default comparer is sufficient. Implementing the other operations like Remove is left as an exercise for the reader

```
public class TwoWayCollection<A, B>
{
    private Dictionary<A, HashSet<B>> byADictionary = new Dictionary<A, HashSet<B>>();
    private Dictionary<B, HashSet<A>> byBDictionary = new Dictionary<B, HashSet<A>>();

    public IEnumerable<B> Get(A a)
    {
        return byADictionary[a];
    }

    public IEnumerable<A> InverseGet(B b)
    {
        return byBDictionary[b];
    }

    public void Add(A a, B b)
    {
        if (!byADictionary.ContainsKey(a))
        {
            byADictionary[a] = new HashSet<B>();
        }
        byADictionary[a].Add(b);
        if (!byBDictionary.ContainsKey(b))
        {
            byBDictionary[b] = new HashSet<A>();
        }
        byBDictionary[b].Add(a);
    }
}
```

Then to use it is literally your proposed code. Both Get and InverseGet approach O(1) as per dictionary

```
TwoWayCollection<int, string> a = new TwoWayCollection<int, string>();
a.Add(1, "a");
a.Add(1, "b");
a.Add(2, "a");
a.Get(1); //returns ["a", "b"]
a.InverseGet("a"); //returns [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/tuples) `List<Tuple<int,string>>` to allow a collection with the same key and `LINQ` to make a query [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/linq/write-linq-queries) to your collection

For example,

```
List<Tuple<int,string>> list = new List<Tuple<int,string>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(23, "Foo"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(23, "Bar"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(25, "Bar"));

var keys = list.Where(x=> x.Item1 == 23).Select(x=> x.Item2); // FOO, BAR
var values = list.Where(x=> x.Item2 == "Bar").Select(x=> x.Item1); ; // 23, 25
```